# omit one drawer on going back with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

The user can navigate like the following:

Path A (ok)
Overview -> GameplayScreen
Back: Overview <- GameplayScreen

Path B (not ok)
Overview -> CreateGame -> GameplayScreen
Back: Overview <- CreateGame <- GameplayScreen

When the user goes back, he lands again on "CreateGame". How can I omit this page, when the user goes back?

```
<Drawer.Navigator
        drawerPosition='right'
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.header_bg,
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },

        }}
          >

            <Drawer.Screen
                name={t("Overview")}
                component={HomeScreen}
                initialParams={{signOut: signOut}}
                options={{
                  headerRight: () => (
                    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
                      <OverflowMenu
                        style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}
                        OverflowIcon={<Ionicons name="ios-more" size={23} color="white" />}
                      >
                        <HiddenItem title={t("signout")} onPress={signOut} />
                      </OverflowMenu>
                    </HeaderButtons>
                  ),
                }}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="GameplayScreen"
               component={GameplayScreen}
               options={{
                 title: t("playing"),
                 gestureEnabled: false,
               }}
                />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="UserChoser"
               component={UserChoser}
               options={{
                 title: t('otherUsers'),
                 gestureEnabled: true,
               }}
                />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="CreateGame"
               component={CreateGame}
               options={{
                 title: t('createGame'),
                 gestureEnabled: true,
               }}
                />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="DeleteGame"
               component={DeleteGame}
               options={{
                 title: t('deleteGame'),
                 gestureEnabled: true,
               }}
                />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="GameHistory"
               component={GameHistory}
               options={{
                 title: t('gameHistory'),
                 gestureEnabled: true,
               }}
                />
             <Drawer.Screen
                name="UserProfile"
                component={UserProfile}
                options={{
                  title: t('userProfile'),
                  gestureEnabled: true,
                }}
              />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "replace()" instead of "navigate()" when navigating to next screen like [Snack.io](https://snack.expo.io/742ZPnUER)

Comment: When I use replace, I don't have the option to go back at all. But I want to go back to 'Overview'

Comment: If you use "replace" when navigating to the 3rd screen then 2nd screen will be omitted as the example shows Snack. You can place the button in 3rd screen to go back